# How can I return custom response from XMLHTTP request?

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, xmlhttprequest

Pulling data from a stocks API, grabbing all the symbol names. I am taking a string symbol from HTML input & using that value to match to the symbols pulled from the API.

I am looking to return a simple boolean if found, which I have added in the request.onload method. When I call/get response from another method I am presented with either undefined or a text response of the object.

I have added a "load" event listener inside the button click listener, I have tried adding the boolean variable inside of the request.send method, I've added a ready state change listener which seems to help but no response type returns the boolean variable from the onload method.

```
const searchInput = document.getElementById("symbol-search-input");
const symbolSearchBtn = document.getElementById("symbol-search-btn");
const symbolSearchMsg = document.getElementById("symbol-status-msg");
const request = new XMLHttpRequest();

symbolSearchBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {

    //Value from html input
    let symbolSearch = searchInput.value;

    if(symbolSearch == "") {
        symbolSearchMsg.innerHTML = "symbol field blank";

    } else {
        //calling XMLHTTPRequest to begin the process
        symbolFound();

        request.onreadystatechange = () => {
            if(request.readyState == 4) {

                if(request.status == 200) {
                    //Below it only returns the entire JSON as text even if I only use "request.response"
                    console.log(request.responseText);

                }

                if(request.status == 404) {
                    console.log('File or resource not found');
                }

            }
        };


let symbolFound = () => {

    request.open('GET', 'https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/ref-data/symbols', true);
    let foundSymbol = false;

    request.onload = function() {
        let data = JSON.parse(this.response);

        if(request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
            let symbolInput = searchInput.value.toUpperCase();

            for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                if(data[i]['symbol'] === symbolInput) {
                    foundSymbol = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            return foundSymbol;

        } else {
            console.log("error");
        }
    };

    request.send();
};
```

I expect to receive a boolean return (true or false), instead, I am receiving the JSON from the API as text/string.

Comment: Try `request.send(foundSymbol);`

Comment: I've tried that with no luck. I still receive the JSON as text.

Comment: You want to return boolean value of `foundSymbol `?  `responseText ` returns string - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseText. You can return the response in object by setting it's responseType to `json` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/response. You can't return boolean value, instead you can send the string as "true" or "false".

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand, I am still rather new to web dev, so maybe I am confused. The first links states that I will only receive the response object from the server. If I understand correctly it seems you are saying that I cannot receive a boolean, which I am ok with, and instead must receive a string. I would be ok with receiving a string response, but how can I receive a custom string? Are you able to provide a code sample? I'm not sure I know how to execute/accomplish what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do it, at least a workaround. Instead of returning any value, I simply had it change the state of a variable and called another function to do what I needed with the boolean. It was also a matter of dissecting the initial function. Check it out.

```
const searchInput = document.getElementById("symbol-search-input");
const symbolSearchBtn = document.getElementById("symbol-search-btn");
const symbolSearchMsg = document.getElementById("symbol-status-msg");
let isSymbolFound;


symbolSearchBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {

    let symbolSearch = searchInput.value;

    if(symbolSearch == "") {
        symbolSearchMsg.innerHTML = "symbol field blank";

    } else {
        isSymbolFound = false;
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhrProcess(xhr);

        xhr.onload = function() {
            let data = JSON.parse(this.response);

            if(xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 400) {
                let symbolInput = symbolSearch.toUpperCase();

                for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    if(data[i]['symbol'] === symbolInput) {
                        isSymbolFound = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                symbolFindProcess();

            } else {
                console.log("error");
            }
        };
    }
});

const symbolFindProcess = () => {
    if(isSymbolFound) {
        //code here
    } else {
        //code here
    }
};

const xhrProcess = (request) => {
    request.open('GET', 'https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/ref-data/symbols', true);
    request.send();
};
```